# Facing issue in converting React function component to class component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I need to convert this from a functional component to a class component so I can take advantage of the componentDidMount method of React.Component.

```
const receivedStyle = {
  marginRight: '0',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
};
const receivedBubble = {
  backgroundColor: '#709AFF',
  color: 'white',
};
const receivedDate = {
  marginRight: '0',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
};

const MessageBubble = ({ message, received }) => (
  <div className="message-bubble" style={received ? receivedStyle : null}>
    <div className="bubble" style={received ? receivedBubble: null}>
      {message.message}
    </div>
    <span className="date" style={received ? receivedDate: null}>{Moment(message.timestamp).startOf('minute').fromNow()}</span>
  </div>
);

export default MessageBubble;
```

Comment: what's the issue? simply put the ui part inside render method and use `this.props` to access the props values. check the doc for [**How to convert Functional Component into Class Component**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what's the problem. Anyway, here it goes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const receivedStyle = {
  marginRight: '0',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
}

const receivedBubble = {
  backgroundColor: '#709AFF',
  color: 'white',
}

const receivedDate = {
  marginRight: '0',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
}

export default class MessageBubble extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    const { message, received } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="message-bubble" style={received ? receivedStyle : null}>
        <div className="bubble" style={received ? receivedBubble: null}>
          {message.message}
        </div>
        <span
          className="date"
          style={received ? receivedDate: null}
        >
          {Moment(message.timestamp).startOf('minute').fromNow()}
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not even that simple also, you missed `class` keyword and forgot to mention how to import Component .

Comment: You've got it :)

Comment: where should i write the code for receivedStyle, receivedBubble and receivedDate?

Comment: Same as before. You can keep them outside the class component.

Comment: How are you rendering `MessageBubble` ?